# puma_http11.so: undefined symbol: SSL_library_init

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linker, openssl, rubygems

I am using Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 64-bit, rails version 5.0.1 and ruby version 2.4.0. 
When I use **bundle install** getting open ssl error while installing gem puma, I fixed it by downloading openssl and using **bundle config build.puma --with-opt-dir=/home/anti/work/myssl**.
Now when I am using **rake db:migrate** getting error

```
rake db:migrate
```

> /home/anti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0-rc1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
>
> /home/anti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0-rc1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
>
> ruby /home/anti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0-rc1/bin/rake db:migrate: symbol
>   lookup error:
>   /home/anti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0-rc1/gems/puma-3.6.2/lib/puma/puma_http11.so:
>   undefined symbol: SSL_library_init

Please help for the solution.

Comment: Also see [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Fixnum and Bignum constants were deprecated per: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26732. This doesn't solve your problem, hence why I'm posting as a comment...informational only. I'm seeing a similar warning when I run tests, stemming from ActiveSupport so will be interested to see the solution.

Comment: I think error is now fixed in rails 5.0.2